# HTML Purifier Symfony2.3

Tags: php, symfony, htmlpurifier

I'd like to add HTML Purifier to my Symfony application, I'm using Symfony2.3.
I found two ways but I have problems on both.

The first one is to directly add the HTML Purifier library into symfony but I don't know realy how to do that, I tried to find tutorials but I don't understand.

The second way is to use this bundle:
https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle
But I don't know how to install it with composer, and I think the documentation is for Symfony 2.0 no higher.

So do you have a solution to easily install HTML Purifier, I don't need twig module given with the bundle.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bundle has a [composer.json](https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle/blob/master/composer.json) file, so you can simply add it to your requirements:

```
require: "exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle": "1.0.*@dev"
```

If you don't need the bundle. you can just add the HTMLPurifier package:

```
require: "ezyang/htmlpurifier": "dev-master"
```

If you see a `composer.json` file in a repository on Github, you can just search on Packagist:

- https://packagist.org/packages/ezyang/htmlpurifier
- https://packagist.org/packages/exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle